# Angular.js: Collection/Model directives to display arbitrary nested data?

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for an Angular.js directive for displaying arbitrary nested JSON data as a view, without knowing the structure of that JSON beforehand.

Consider the following JSON resource at REST endpoint `/api/orgranisations/:organisation_id/`:

```
{
    "organisation_name": "Horns and Hoofs Limited",
    "employees": [
        {
            "last_name": "Pound",
            "age": 90,
            "position": "CEO",
            "previous_projects": {
                "Marcella Vests": "member",
                "Intensivenik": "CEO"
            }
        },
        {
            "last_name": "Bender",
            "age": 31
            "position": "CTO"
            "previous_projects": {
                "12 chairs": "CTO",
                "Sons of Lt. Schmidt": "member"
            }
        },
        {
            "last_name": "Balaganov",
            "age": 25
            "position": "Head of Hoofs dpt."
            "previous_projects": {
                "Sons of Lt. Schmidt": "member"
            }
        },
        {
            "last_name": "Panikovsky",
            "age": 60
            "position": "attendant"
            "previous_projects": {
                "Blind man": "CEO"
                "Sons of Lt. Schmidt": "member"
            }
        }
    ]


}
```

As a human you classify elements of this JSON as tree of Primitive Types, Models and Collections of Models (I'm using `Backbone.js` terminology):

```
{
    "organisation_name": Primitive Type,
    "employees": Collection(EmployeeModel)
}
```

where EmployeeModel is

```
{
    "last_name": Primitive Type,
    "age": Ptimitive Type,
    "position": Primitive Type,
    "previous_projects": Collection(PrevProjectModel)
}
```

where PrevProjectModel is `id: Primitive Type`.

**I'm looking for Collection and Model Angular.js directives** with the following capabilities:

A Collection can be represented as a table of Models, capable of performing basic operations, such as "create model", "delete model" and "drag-n-drop sort":

[image]

A Model can be represented as a collapsible table, like this:

[image]

So far I've found:

- [recursive repeater project](https://github.com/tchatel/angular-treeRepeat)
- [blog post, implementing Collection and Model (called Member here)](http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/nested-recursive-directives-in-angular/).
- [angular tree project](https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-tree)

Comment: This is very broad. It also sounds like something you can create yourself relatively easily. Rendering the table with collapse/expand functionality is no big deal. DnD would require external plugin I guess (maybe jQuery). After that you can wrap it all into one custom directive.

Comment: Really not clear what specific problem is. There is no need in data shown for a recursive directive. A simple nested repeat would do what you need

Comment: @dfsq Probably, you're right. I just expected a popular solution to exist, as this task is very-very common.

Comment: @charlietfl The question is: haven't you stumbled upon a well-known implementation of Collection directive, Model directive and JSON analyzer, that would look at JSON and automatically convert it into a tree of Collection and Model directives?

Comment: yes  ... `ng-repeat`. No idea what you mean by *"json analyzer"*. What is shown in images is trivial to create

Comment: @charlietfl  JSON analyzer means, that frontend code knows nothing about JSON structure before it comes from backend. This should work for an arbitrary JSON from arbitrary REST API endpoint. It should adequately represent any JSON data as a nested set of modifiable, collapsible tables.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/bfanger/angular-activerecord
It is a backbone like model/collection module for angular. I used it in a few projects.